# nginx resolve (point) everything to different ip except specific file and subdirectory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, resolve

So i have posted similar question on stackoverflow but i think this is more appropriate section for this.

What i have now is one travel blog and on that blog i have whitelabel for tickets/booking.

whitelabel website is basically subdomain which is pointing to alias domain

So let's say my website is `mytravelblog.com` and whitelabel is `whitelabel.otheragency.com` and that is pointing to my subdomain which is in subfolder so

`mytravelblog.com/tickets` opens `whitelabel.otheragency.com` but i want to switch now for my whitelabel to be main website, but problem is they don't give robots.txt so i would have to deliver that and keep it on my hosting and also i want to keep my blog but just switch it to subfolder.

So whitelabel is giving me 2 methods to access their whitelabel, `whitelabel.otheragency.com` and resolve to their ip

Can i somehow do a redirection or proxy setup to resolve everything that is from whitelabel on my main domain but everything that is from subdirectory `blog` to my hosted blog website and `robots.txt` to my hosted robots.txt file.

So this is how it should be

`mytravelblog.com` open `whitelabel.otheragency.com` but still under my domain
`mytravelblog.com/tickets` open `whitelabel.otheragency.com/tickets` and so for the rest of subfolders

`mytravelblog.com/blog` open my blog website that is on my hosting and any other subfolders
`mytravelblog.com/blog/10-most-beautiful-beaches` to open my blog post
`mytravelblog.com/sitemap.xml` opens my generated sitemap which i also host
`mytravelblog.com/robots.txt` opens my generated robots.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
location / {
    ... other proxy_pass settings ...
    proxy_pass http://whitelabel.otheragency.com;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location = /sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location /blog {
    try_files /path/to/front_controller =404;
}
```

Comment: I found solution like 30 minutes after posting this. And it's exactly as your suggestion, except i don't put =404 at the end, im guessing this is if page is not found fallback? Another problem i encounter is now i can't login to whitelabel website with this method.

Comment: I assume that is because the whitelabel website expects that it is accessed via `whitelabel.otheragency.com`, not `mytravelblog.com`.

Comment: no, it was working before, my logins and also new user registrations and bookings. It also works when i use DNS to resolve to their ip i just tested, but it's not working like this. I'll google around to find a solution if i can.